# x:Type not found in user control library

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to create a `ResourceDictionary` inside a WPF UserControl Library project. When I add the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=GreyBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LightBlueBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OrangeBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LightOrange}" Duration="0:0:.1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I get an error saying:

```
The type 'x:Type' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

I am declaring x as:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

This works when I create a resource dictionary inside a WPF application project, but not inside a UserControl Library project. Any idea why?

Comment: Don't know why it's happening, a workaround is to just remove the {x:Type} text though, i.e. `TargetType="Button"`. The same error occurs in Silverlight AFAIK.

Comment: But does not always happen. At least the above style works fine for me in a resource dictionary in a newly created (.Net 4.0) WPF User Control Library project.

Comment: I'm using VS2012 Professional and creating a .Net 3.5 WPF User Control Library.

Comment: I'm experiencing *exactly* the behaviour described by FlyingStreudel in exactly the same context. Additional observation: if you create a WPF app to test the newly minted widget, (a) it works at run-time (b) at design-time, clicking anywhere on the design surface of the test window produces a NullReferenceException. My namespace imports are *exactly* as described by AlSki.

Comment: Changing the UserControl project framework version from 3.5 to 4 caused the problem to go away. Visual Studio began to correctly resolve x:Type as TypeExtension, as indicated by a hovertip. However, the widget was then unavailable for use with the test project which was still framework 3.5. Fascinatingly, changing the widget back to fw35 left me without errors in the XAML designer and a test program that cease to give NREs.

Comment: But restarting Visual Studio brings us back to square one. So, I think it's a problem with the designer and the way it's resolving stuff, or at least with the configuration of a default 3.5 project.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This happened to me when I was writing an IE Extension and wanted to create WPF User Controls. Since the project was not originally a WPF project there was no reference to **System.Xaml**, adding said reference fixed the issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me!  The project did compile but always displayed errors (especially annoying with the Solution Explorer Errors feature of the Productivity Power Tools extension).

Comment: Encountered the same problem/solution, but the culprit was "System.Presentation".

Answer (score 3):

Had the same looking issue in my project. I've solved it by switching Target Framework from .NET 3.0 to 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree, here's my decalaration from a UserControl that does work.

```
<UserControl x:Class="RedGreenRefactor.View.TestResultsGraph"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

Is there any chance that the error is telling you exactly what is wrong? Have you got all the assemblies referenced that you need?

Creating a new WPF application I get the following.

[image: WPF default references]

Comment: Is that for a 3.5 or 4.0 library? I'm guessing 4.0 as Microsoft.CSharp and System.Xaml aren't 3.5

Comment: 4.5 actually, but you can always create a new empty wpf and compare for any version

Comment: The references are identical between the wpf app project and the control library.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the root

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="..."
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

, i.e. where do you define x? Apart from that

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
```

also works.